# Не отображается фоновое изображение

Tags: css, bootstrap

Я скачал boostrap, распаковал и подключил css.

Хочу сделать блок с текстом и иконками, а на заднем фоне - картинка.

Уже часа 2 пытаюсь картинку прикрутить =(
Фон при этом отображается.

Вот код:

css:

```
.hero {
background-image: url:('../img/highway.jpg') 50% 50% no-repeat;
background-color: #464646;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>
    <body>
     <section class="hero">
     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top"> 
                 <div class="container">
                     <div class="navbar-header">
                         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive">
                         <span class="sr-only">Open</span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                         </button>      
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ракодонск</a>
                     </div>  

                      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive"> 
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="#">Разд</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Два</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Три</a></li>              
                        </ul>
                     </div>                                    
              </div>       
      </div>         






      <section class="hero">

        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Название сайта</h1>
           <p><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-spin"></i></p>
           <p><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></p>
         </div>                    
    </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


     </section>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Chrome выдает `invalid property value`.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Беретесь за фреймворк без элементарных знаний css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойство background-image принимает только адрес картинки, а у вас так же указаны дополнительные параметры. Так же у вас стоит двоеточие до url(), там оно не нужно.

В вашем случае должно быть так:

```
.hero {
background-image: url('../img/highway.jpg');
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #464646;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Все работает!